# PDFTK can't find files - anywhere even home folder

Tags: linux, terminal, pdftk

Similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533839/why-is-pdftk-saying-it-cant-find-files-that-are-right-there/572667?noredirect=1#comment1065733_572667) , but the solution of moving files to the home directory didn't sort it for me. So I don't think its a problem with permissions.

This is the jist of the error I got:

```
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   18.png
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

And the command entered:

```
pdftk 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png 7.png 8.png 9.png 10.png 11.png 12.png 13.png 14.png 15.png 16.png 17.png 18.png cat output trippyblsmq.pdf
```

Comment: What does `stat 18.png` show?

Comment: stat: cannot stat '18.png': No such file or directory

Answer (score 5):

The `pdftk` error, “Unable to find file” is somewhat misleading: the problem isn’t that the input files don’t exist, but that they’re not PDFs.

`pdftk` expects PDFs as input, it can’t import PDFs. You’ll need another tool, such as ImageMagick, to convert your PNGs to a PDF.

Comment: sorry no... I didn't copy all the output - it gave the same error on all the files. and the command should be to convert all these .png s to a pdf file

Comment: and they exist. I can see them in the /home folder, and open them

Comment: So why does `stat 18.png` fail? That’s weird. But see my update, the problem isn’t that `pdftk` can’t find files, it’s that it can’t process them.

Comment: I was following instructions saying pdftk can convert png to pdf without losing much resolution, like other apps might. guess that was wrong